# Non code signed Mac app does not work on another Mac

Tags: macos, distribution, code-signing

I have an app and would like to distribute it to a friend. I removed all code signing (app and developer certificate), built the archive and then send it to my friend. When my friend tried to install the app on her Mac it gave her the message "xxxxx can’t be installed on this computer". She is running the latest version of OSX 10.6.7.

Any suggestions as to why the application could not be installed on her computer?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you were building for 64 bits and she had a 32-bit processor (the Core Duo)?

Comment: No. Her computer is 64-bit and the app was built for 64 bits.